# iTunes iPhone 3GS Where are the video recordings stored on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, video, iphone, itunes, recording

When you record video with an iPhone 3gs and then backup using iTunes where are those video file stored? I'm trying to retrieve some lost files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of iPhone OS are you using?

It's only since 3.0 that videos are backed up. And since 3.1 it *won't* back up videos over 2gb.

More info from [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766)

From that same article:

> The folder where your backup data is
>   stored changes depending on the
>   computer's operating system. Since
>   iTunes only keeps one backup per
>   device, you should ensure the backup
>   folder is included in your periodic
>   data backup routine.

It looks like if you've backed up the iPhone since losing/removing the videos from the device they *won't* be in the backup.

In XP the backup is stored at:

> \Documents and
>   Settings(username)\Application
>   Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\